# Last line ouputs two combined outputs trouble? If else statements

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm having a hard time trying to find why my program is outputting twice in my last output line.

If I try inputs of 5 and 500 it works but when I try to use a bigger number for the second input like 500000 i get two different outputs combined in the last output line.

Below is my code.
I'm pretty sure its my last if else statements but I don't see the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double estimatedSales;
    double copyPrice;
    double netMade;
    double firstOp_net;
    double secondOp_net;
    double thirdOp_net;
    double cashBefore = 5000;
    double cashAfter = 20000;
    const double FIRST_RATE = .125;
    const double SECOND_RATE1 = .10;
    const double SECOND_RATE2 = .14;
    double bestPrice;


    cout << "Enter the price for a copy of your novel\n";
    cin >> copyPrice;
    cout << "Enter the estimated number of copies that will be sold\n";
    cin >> estimatedSales;

    netMade = copyPrice * estimatedSales;

    cout << "It is estimated that your novel will generate $" << netMade << " of revenue.\n" ;

    firstOp_net = cashBefore + cashAfter;
    secondOp_net = netMade * FIRST_RATE;

    if (estimatedSales <= 4000) {
        thirdOp_net = netMade * SECOND_RATE1;
    } else { 
        thirdOp_net = netMade * SECOND_RATE2;
    }

    cout << "Royalties you keep for Option 1 is $" << firstOp_net <<"\n";
    cout << "Royalties you keep for Option 2 is $" << secondOp_net <<"\n";
    cout << "Royalties you keep for Option 3 is $" << thirdOp_net <<"\n";

    if (firstOp_net > secondOp_net) {
        bestPrice = firstOp_net;
    } else {
        cout<< "Your best bet would be to go with your 2nd Option for $"<< secondOp_net;
    }
    if (bestPrice > thirdOp_net) {
        cout << "Your best bet would be to go with your 1st Option for $"<< firstOp_net;
    } else {
        cout<< "Your best bet would be to go with your 3rd Option for $"<<thirdOp_net;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
Enter the price for a copy of your novel
5
Enter the estimated number of copies that will be sold
500000
It is estimated that your novel will generate $2.5e+06 of revenue.
Royalties you keep for Option 1 is $25000
Royalties you keep for Option 2 is $312500
Royalties you keep for Option 3 is $350000
Your best bet would be to go with your 2nd Option for $312500Your best bet would be to go with your 3rd Option for $350000
```

This is what I was expecting:

```
Enter the price for a copy of your novel
5
Enter the estimated number of copies that will be sold
500000
It is estimated that your novel will generate $2.5e+06 of revenue.
Royalties you keep for Option 1 is $25000
Royalties you keep for Option 2 is $312500
Royalties you keep for Option 3 is $350000
Your best bet would be to go with your 3rd Option for $350000
```

Comment: Can you add the output and the expected output?

Comment: You'll get two outputs whenever the first condition is false.

Comment: I have an unrelated comment. Looking at some of the statements, the Elvis operator (?:) would shorten it a lot. Maybe have a look at this: thirdOp_net = netMade * (estimatedSales <= 4000? SECOND_RATE1 : SECOND_RATE2);

Comment: Personally, I find the `?:` operator less obvious than an `if`/`else`.  Particularly when you start nesting them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is the logic in the last part, while calculating the Royalties. Its actually simple logic and you can reduce the amount of code.

Here is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

double estimatedSales;
double copyPrice;
double netMade;
double firstOp_net;
double secondOp_net;
double thirdOp_net;
double cashBefore = 5000;
double cashAfter = 20000;
const double FIRST_RATE = .125;
const double SECOND_RATE1 = .10;
const double SECOND_RATE2 = .14;
double bestPrice;


cout << "Enter the price for a copy of your novel\n";
cin >> copyPrice;
cout << "Enter the estimated number of copies that will be sold\n";
cin >> estimatedSales;

netMade = copyPrice*estimatedSales;

cout << "It is estimated that your novel will generate $" << netMade << " of revenue.\n" ;

firstOp_net = cashBefore+cashAfter;
secondOp_net = netMade*FIRST_RATE;

if (estimatedSales <= 4000)
    { thirdOp_net = netMade*SECOND_RATE1;
    }
else { thirdOp_net = netMade*SECOND_RATE2;
    }

cout << "Royalties you keep for Option 1 is $" << firstOp_net <<"\n";
cout << "Royalties you keep for Option 2 is $" << secondOp_net <<"\n";
cout << "Royalties you keep for Option 3 is $" << thirdOp_net <<"\n";

double big = firstOp_net;

if(big<secondOp_net)
{
    big = secondOp_net;
}
if(big<thirdOp_net)
{
    big = thirdOp_net;
}


    cout << "Your best bet would be to go with your 1st Option for $"<< big;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You, much appreciated.

Comment: @miggs if you found this answer useful please upvote and accept it as the answer